# Vue-CLI 3 check file exists by path file?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

#### [My directory structure]

```
MyProject
├─ public
|  └─ rar
|      ├─ myFile.zip
|      ├─ other.zip
|         ...
├─ node_modules
├─ src
├─ test
```

i want to check file exists in `public/rar/myFile.zip`

#### [My Code try]

```
import fs from "fs";

export default {
  name: "home",
  methods: {
    isFileExists() {
      if (fs.existsSync("../rar/myFile.zip")) {
        console.log("file found");
      } else {
        console.log("sorry, file not found");
    },
  },
};
```

above code i try using `fs` but not working

Please help. I need some code for fix it.

## Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `const fs = require('fs');` I saw that from another answer

Comment: bro, same it's not working

Comment: what if you just do `var f = fs.existsSync("../rar/myFile.zip")` the console log `f`?

Comment: results is : [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function"

Comment: Well thats your error, which fs library are u using and where did you get that line of code

Comment: why error. I run npm install "fs" already.

Comment: It is not fs, but the existsSync that is causing the issue

Comment: umm, you have solution by not use "fs" ?

Comment: Check the second example https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-check-if-file-exists-node/

Comment: Also, try the exception handler, i.e. try/catch block, it will give you meaningful errors

Answer (score 4):

Just use the "try catch" and it will work like charm.

**Example:**

```
try {
  let fileName = require('../rar/myFile.zip');
  console.log("file found");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("sorry, file not found");
}
```

Comment: require will not work in vite. Any solution for vite ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists by making http request. You can use either ajax or axios. Axios is way faster.